# Pandas: count values based on another column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to caunt all values from `col2` based on `col1` name with Pandas?

Input:

```
col1     col2
-------------
one      1
two      2
three    1
one      4
two      4
three    2
```

Output:

```
col1     col2
-------------
one      5
two      6
three    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index=False)['col2'].sum()
# df.set_index('col1').sum(level='col1').reset_index() #decrepated in future

    col1  col2
0    one     5
1  three     3
2    two     6
```